# finding essential prime implicants

Tags: boolean-algebra

> F(w,x,y,z)=Σ(0,1,2,4,5,6,7,10,15)

which one is correct, or both wrong. i'm confused about finding prime implicants at top right and bottom right
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$w'yz'$ is not a prime implicant: it is subsumed by $w'z'$, which is not essential. $x'y'z'$ is essential because it covers the distinguished minterm $wx'y'z'$.